# Generate largest number of 10 inputs

Tags: ruby, scripting

New to scripting here. Basically, I am needing to write a program to accept 10 input numbers and return the largest in the list.

I have this code, but obviously it is not running:

```
class Generator

  def getNumbers
    number = Array.new

    puts "To begin, You will need to enter your numbers."
    print "Press Enter to continue."
    Console_Screen.pause

    10.times do
      print "\nPlease enter any number: "
      input = STDIN.gets
      input.chop!
      list.push
      return list 
    end

    list.push(number)
    print list.max
  end
end


Console_Screen.new
Find = Generator.new

end
```

Can anyone help me with what I coded incorrectly?

Comment: When you say "it is not running" here, it would be good to post what kind of error you are getting.

Comment: I am actually have to change the program because I wasn't using the correct variables. The instructions are:  Write a Ruby application that allows a user to input a series of 10 integers and determines and prints the largest integer. Your program should use at least the following three variables:
a) counter: A counter to count to 10 (i.e., to keep track of how many numbers have been input and to determine when all 10 numbers have been processed).
b) number: The integer most recently input by the user.
c) largest: The largest number found so far.

Comment: Using `return` inside a `do...end` block is a mistake here. Also you're not pushing any values to your list. Try `list.push input`. You can also do things like `10.times.map` and let that block do the work of creating an array for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code. Among them I may point:

1) You created an array named `number` to store your numbers and then tried to push them to another variable named `list`;

2) As @tadman pointed, you used a return inside a `times` block and this makes the block to be executed only once;

3) You never invoked getNumbers to make your process really happen!

This code would do what you need:

```
class Generator

  def get_numbers
    numbers = Array.new

    puts "To begin, You will need to enter your numbers."
    puts

    10.times do
      print "\nPlease enter any number: "
      input = STDIN.gets
      input.chop!
      numbers.push(input.to_i)
    end

    print numbers.max
  end
end

Find = Generator.new
Find.get_numbers
```

Notice that I changed the name of your method from `getNumbers` to `get_numbers`, which is much more Ruby-like.

Notice that I also changed the name of your array from `number` to `numbers`, 'cause it will store numbers, not a single number. Naming your varables correctly may help you to think correctly about your problem. It also helps when it comes for other people reading your program. Even you, six months later, will have problems to understand your own code if you don't name things correctly an comment you code well.

By the way, I also pushed the numbers to `numbers` as integer, using `#to_i`. This will make the numbers be compared as numbers, not as strings. If you researsh a bit you'll find out this could be a bit different. If someone enters `0300` as a number, it will be considered to be smaller then `200` as string, but when converted to integers, they will be in the correct order.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for everyone's help. This is only the second program I have written in Ruby. So, learning everything from scratch! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach perhaps:

```
#script.rb
nums = []
10.times do |c|
  puts "enter number #{c+1}"
  nums << gets.to_i
end

puts "max number is #{nums.max}"
```

#### Example

```
$ ruby script.rb
enter number 1
#5
enter number 2
#3
enter number 3
#66
enter number 4
#4
enter number 5
#3
enter number 6
#2
enter number 7
#1
enter number 8
#6
enter number 9
#9
enter number 10
#0  
#max number is 66
```

Comment: Of course this is much more Ruby-like! I tried o keep the same structure the OP used, to make it easier for him to understand. But your approach is much better, of course.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida ha I just wanted to offer a different approach since you had already nicely explained the shortcomings of the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same assignment and this is what I ended up creating. (I had to get a little more involved with input control and I'm sure there's easier ways of doing this. Also had to utilize the variables as part of the grade. I assume to  prevent me from ripping off the code above.)

```
class Screen
  def cls
    puts ("\n" * 25)
    puts "\a" 
  end

  def pause
    STDIN.gets
  end    
end

Console_Screen = Screen.new

num = [] #array to store user input

$counter = 1
loop do

  puts "Please enter number " + $counter.to_s + " of a series of 10 numbers in order to determine the largest."
  # Console_Screen.pause
  loop do
    print "Enter Number Here:"
    number = gets.chomp       
    num << number.to_i if number =~ /[0-9]/ #only writes to the array if it's a number
    break if number =~ /[0-9]/ #only allow numbers
  end

  $counter += 1
  break if $counter == 11

end

puts "Press Enter to have your numbers sorted and the largest presented to you."

Console_Screen.pause   

largest = num.max
puts "This is your largest number: " + largest.to_s
Console_Screen.pause
```